# (totally) (M,P)-generic forcing condition

Tags: logic, set-theory, forcing

We say a cardinal $\theta$ is *sufficiently large* for a forcing $Q$ if $\mathcal{P}(\mathcal{P}(Q)) \in H(\theta)$.

And a set $M$ is a *suitable model* for $Q$ if $Q \in M$ and $M \prec H(\theta)$, $M$ countable, for some $\theta$ which is sufficiently large for $Q$.

For a suitable model $M$ for $Q$ and a condition $q \in Q$ we say that $q$ is *$(M,Q)$-generic* if whenever $r \leqslant q$, $D \in M$ dense, $D \subset Q$, $r$ is compatible with an element of $D \cap M$.

If $\lbrace p \in Q \cap M \colon q \leqslant p \rbrace$ is an $(M,Q)$-generic filter, then $q$ is called *totally $(M,Q)$-generic*.

$Q$ is *totally proper* if whenever $M$ is a suitable model for $Q$ and $q \in Q \cap M$, $q$ has a totally $(M,Q)$-generic extension.

---

Let $Q$ a totally proper forcing and $M$ a suitable model for $Q$.
Then not every $(M,Q)$-generic condition needs to be totally $(M,Q)$-generic.

But is it possible to extend every $(M,Q)$-generic condition to a totally $(M,Q)$-generic condition?

---

I would think yes but no proof.

Comment: Just to give an example, every $\sigma$-closed forcing is totally proper. And in a $\sigma$-closed forcing, every $(M,Q)$-generic condition can be easily extended to a totally generic condition as well.

Comment: As a note, the obvious attempt of doing this by showing that an $(M,Q)$-generic condition can be extended into $M$ doesn't work; this fails even for countably closed forcings.

Comment: Is there a natural example for a totally proper, but not $\sigma$-closed forcing?

Comment: @AsafKaragila It was shown by Eisworth and Roitman that totally proper is equivalent to proper + countably distributive (and also proper + doesn't add reals). So a Suslin tree is an example, I guess.

Comment: @Miha: That makes some sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the following argument works to show that generic conditions do extend to totally generic ones.

As mentioned in the comments, a poset $Q$ is totally proper iff it is proper and countably distributive. I will only need the forward direction and this isn't difficult to see: given a condition $p$ and a name $\dot{f}$ for a countable sequence take a suitable $M\ni p,\dot{f}$. Now, for each $n$, the hull $M$ also contains the dense set of conditions deciding $\dot{f}(n)$. It follows that any totally $(M,Q)$-generic condition must decide $\dot{f}$, and, since we can find one below $p$, it is dense in $Q$ that $\dot{f}$ is in the ground model.

For the main argument let $Q$ be totally proper, $M$ a suitable model and $q$ an $(M,Q)$-generic condition. Enumerate the maximal antichains in $M$ by $\langle A_n;n<\omega\rangle$. For each $n$ let $D_n$ be the set of conditions extending some element of $A_n\cap M$. Then $D_n$ is open dense below $q$, since this condition was $(M,Q)$-generic. Since $Q$ is countably distributive, $\bigcap_n D_n$ is dense below $q$ and any condition in this intersection is totally $(M,Q)$-generic. So, in fact, $q$ extends to many totally $(M,Q)$-generic conditions.

Comment: I guess this argument actually shows the other direction of the characterization of total properness, since I only used properness and countable distributivity.